# the function of "to"

Tags: meaning-in-context, to-infinitive

> The Department of  Commerce sums the payments (made to resources) ***to*** arrive at GDP in the form of compensation of employees, rents, profits, net interest, indirect taxes and depreciation.

I bracketed **made to resources** as I think it is a participle phrase and functions as a adjective (according to this site : http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/participlephrase.htm),
therefore can be ignored when understanding the function of **to** in the context.

And the **to** here doesn't seem to tell the purpose of **sums the payments**, so the only interpretation I can come up with is :

> The Department of Commerce sums the payments, and the payments arrive at GDP in the form of compensation of employees, rents, profits, net interest, indirect taxes and depreciation.

So the **to** in the original context probably acts as an object complement, the object being **payments** and **to arrive at..** being the complement. 
 (according to this site:  https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Object-Complements.htm)

Is my understanding of the meaning of the context and the function of **to** correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sample sentence (taken from online quizlets, I think):

The Department of Commerce sums the payments (made to resources) to arrive at GDP in the form of compensation of employees, rents, profits, net interest, indirect taxes and depreciation.

**made to resources** is adjectival.

But: **to** arrive at GDP means: in order to arrive at GDP.

It explains the purpose of the DOC adding up the payments.

[by the way, in American English we say add up the payments here, and not sums the payments. It sounds better.]

It is an infinitive phrase AKA infinitival clause after the main verb.

[I have a special way of analyzing this which is not known generally to English-speaking linguists. The function word "to" sets up a relationship between "The Department of Commerce sums the payments" and what comes after "to", traditionally described as purpose. Please see directly observable markers: [directly observable markers and two-phase theory theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_Adamczewski)
The purpose of adding up the payments is precisely: to arrive at GDP.

Comment: Yes. I was reading the sentence and immediately thought that *to* meant *in order to*. If you want to drop the repeated use of *to*, you can also say *so that they*.

Answer (score 1):

> *The Department of Commerce sums the payments (made to resources)* [*to*
>   *arrive at GDP in the form of compensation of employees, rents,*
>   *profits, net interest, indirect taxes and depreciation*].

The constituent "made to resources" is a past-participial clause modifying "payments". Semantically, it's similar to the relative clause in ... *payments that are made to resources.*

"To" is a subordinator functioning as 'marker'. It introduces the bracketed *to*-infinitival clause, which is probably best analysed as a result adjunct in clause structure.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that "to" can be an interpreted as a result adjunct.

Comment: @tsaizi It's not just "to" that is a result adjunct, but the whole infinitival clause _to arrive at GDP in the form of compensation of employees, rents, profits, net interest, indirect taxes and depreciation_. "To" is a subordinator that introduces the infinitival clause.

Comment: Thank you so much again, is there a website you would recommend for understanding infinitive clause? I found some , but none of them cover the idea of infinitive's being result adjunct.

Comment: @tsaizi Here's a link to a chart of all the various types of adjunct [link](https://dspace.aab-edu.net/bitstream/handle/123456789/702/79502760-48ba-46b9-ba57-e8c4995546c5.pdf?sequence=10&isAllowed=y)

Comment: Thank you again for the helpful answers and the link!

Comment: I've been studying the knowledge in the link, and was wondering if infinitive clause is a result adjunct, can it  be the equivalent of "in order to"? Ex: He recalled what he did to his friends **to cause them to isolate him**.

Comment: @tsaizi It has the form of a purpose adjunct, but the meaning of a result one!